# Add a "hasedits:" search option

Tags: feature-request, search, edits

I would like there to be an option to search for questions that have been unedited. For example, a search for a question with edits might look like this: "hasedits:0 iOS animation". The syntax is similar to the syntax of the other search features like "hasaccepted:" and "isaccepted:" shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search).

Comment: Interesting suggestion, but I'm having a hard time imagining what purpose it would have?

Comment: @Pekka I would think just out of curiosity's sake.

Comment: If one wanted to search for answers to edit with other parameters too. For example, if I only answer questions with the iPhone and iOS tag, then I could search like this: "[iphone][ios] hasedits:0". This is similar to the review tag except one can specify additional parameters. Hope this clears up the question about the purpose of this feature.

Comment: I'm still not sure what purpose it would serve. What's useful about finding content that has been edited? Maybe it's me, but I'm just not seeing it

Comment: @Pekka, I would imagine it being a yes/no flag. I could see it being abused for older posts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Pekka, I don't see this search option having any purpose at all.

You've only identified one side of the search feature here. You say it would be nice to be able to search for posts in your tags that have never been edited. While the search results *may* yield something useful to you, **you'd be just as likely finding something to edit without the extra search option**. Whether or not a post has been edited before has absolutely no bearing on whether or not the post can be edited further.

Something which has never been edited may be in that state because there is nothing to edit, while something that has been edited three or four times could still have major issues that could be edited. I don't see how this search option would be helpful to the community.

Comment: Now that I have reviewed your answers, I realize that you are correct. There isn't much purpose for a feature like this. Thanks